# Grid View Doesn't Refresh on Application Load

Tags: android, android-gridview

[EDIT: Was able to solve this by passing a blank image to the list array on fragment load]

I am working on an app where grid views are refreshed dynamically fetching data from API. My gridview is not refrishing on load. The refresh is happening on clicking other options (like sort) or by just changing orientation in the app. How do I get it to refresh on load. I have tried calling the refresh function from onStart(), onCreate() and onCreateView() but it isn't working.

Github: https://github.com/abhrajitmukherjee/PopularMovies

Main code:

```
public class MainActivityFragment extends Fragment {

    private ImageAdapter mImageAdapter;
    public ArrayList<String[]> mThumbIds;
    private GridView gridview;

    public MainActivityFragment() {

    }

    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        // Add this line in order for this fragment to handle menu events.

        setHasOptionsMenu(true);

    }

    @Override
    public void onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu, MenuInflater inflater) {
        inflater.inflate(R.menu.menu_fragment_main, menu);
    }

    @Override
    public void onActivityCreated(@Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onActivityCreated(savedInstanceState);
        Log.v("Initiate","Starts here-------------------");
        updateMovieThumbs(getString(R.string.base_uri_popular));
        gridview = (GridView) getActivity().findViewById(R.id.gridview);
        mImageAdapter = new ImageAdapter(getActivity());
        gridview.setAdapter(mImageAdapter);
        updateMovieThumbs(getString(R.string.base_uri_popular));



        gridview.setOnItemClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener() {
            public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View v,
                                    int position, long id) {
                Intent intent = new Intent(getActivity(), MovieDetailsActivity.class)
                        .putExtra(getString(R.string.intent_poster_path), mThumbIds.get(position)[0])
                        .putExtra(getString(R.string.intent_title),mThumbIds.get(position)[1])
                        .putExtra(getString(R.string.intent_overview),mThumbIds.get(position)[2])
                        .putExtra(getString(R.string.intent_vote_avg),mThumbIds.get(position)[3])
                        .putExtra(getString(R.string.intent_release_date),mThumbIds.get(position)[4]);


                startActivity(intent);
            }
        });
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
        // Handle action bar item clicks here. The action bar will
        // automatically handle clicks on the Home/Up button, so long
        // as you specify a parent activity in AndroidManifest.xml.
        int id = item.getItemId();

        if (id == R.id.action_toprated) {
            updateMovieThumbs(getString(R.string.base_uri_toprated));


        } else if (id == R.id.action_popular) {
            updateMovieThumbs(getString(R.string.base_uri_popular));
        }



        return true;
    }

    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                             Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        View v = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_main, container, false);
        mThumbIds = new ArrayList<String[]>();

        return v;
    }

    @Override
    public void onStart() {
        super.onStart();

    }


    private void updateMovieThumbs(String sortType) {
        FetchMovieDatabase movieTask = new FetchMovieDatabase();
        movieTask.execute(sortType);
        Log.v("getCount", "Get Main count=" + Integer.toString(mThumbIds.size()));


    }


    public class FetchMovieDatabase extends AsyncTask<String, Void, ArrayList<String[]>> {

        private final String LOG_TAG = FetchMovieDatabase.class.getSimpleName();


        private ArrayList<String[]> getMovieDataJson(String movieJsonStr)
                throws JSONException {

            final String RESULTS = "results";
            final String ORIGINAL_TITLE="original_title";
            final String POSTER="poster_path";
            final String OVERVIEW="overview";
            final String VOTES="vote_average";
            final String RELEASE="release_date";
            ArrayList<String[]> newThumbids=new ArrayList<String[]>();

            JSONObject movieJson = new JSONObject(movieJsonStr);
            JSONArray movieArray = movieJson.getJSONArray(RESULTS);
            for (int i = 0; i < movieArray.length(); i++) {
                JSONObject results = movieArray.getJSONObject(i);

                String posterPath = getString(R.string.api_image_base_path)+results.getString(POSTER);
                String title=results.getString(ORIGINAL_TITLE);
                String overview=results.getString(OVERVIEW);
                String voteAvg=results.getString(VOTES);
                String releaseDate=results.getString(RELEASE);
                String[] outputAttr={posterPath,title,overview,voteAvg,releaseDate};
                Log.v(LOG_TAG, posterPath);

                newThumbids.add(outputAttr);
                Log.v(LOG_TAG, Integer.toString(newThumbids.size()));

            }
            return newThumbids;


        }

        @Override
        protected ArrayList<String[]> doInBackground(String... params) {

            if (params.length == 0) {
                return null;
            }
            HttpURLConnection urlConnection = null;
            BufferedReader reader = null;

            String movieJsonStr = null;


            try {

                final String BASE_URL = params[0];

                final String API_KEY = "api_key";



                Uri builtUri = Uri.parse(BASE_URL).buildUpon()
                        .appendQueryParameter(API_KEY, BuildConfig.MOVIES_API_KEY)
                        .build();


                URL url = new URL(builtUri.toString());

                urlConnection = (HttpURLConnection) url.openConnection();
                urlConnection.setRequestMethod("GET");
                urlConnection.connect();

                // Read the input stream into a String
                InputStream inputStream = urlConnection.getInputStream();
                StringBuffer buffer = new StringBuffer();
                if (inputStream == null) {
                    // Nothing to do.
                    return null;
                }
                reader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(inputStream));

                String line;
                while ((line = reader.readLine()) != null) {
                    buffer.append(line + "\n");
                }

                if (buffer.length() == 0) {

                    return null;
                }
                movieJsonStr = buffer.toString();
            } catch (IOException e) {
                Log.e(LOG_TAG, "Error ", e);

                return null;
            } finally {
                if (urlConnection != null) {
                    urlConnection.disconnect();
                }
                if (reader != null) {
                    try {
                        reader.close();
                    } catch (final IOException e) {
                        Log.e(LOG_TAG, "Error closing stream", e);
                    }
                }
            }

            try {
                return getMovieDataJson(movieJsonStr);
            } catch (JSONException e) {
                Log.e(LOG_TAG, e.getMessage(), e);
                e.printStackTrace();
            }

            return null;
        }

        @Override
        protected void onPostExecute(ArrayList<String[]> result) {
            if (result != null) {
                if (mThumbIds.size()>0){
                    mThumbIds.clear();
                }

                mThumbIds = (ArrayList<String[]>) result.clone();
                Log.v(LOG_TAG, "Postexecute count:"+Integer.toString( mThumbIds.size()));
                mImageAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged();

            }
        }
    }


    public class ImageAdapter extends BaseAdapter {
        private Context mContext;

        public ImageAdapter(Context c) {
            mContext = c;
        }

        public int getCount() {

            Log.v("getCount", "Get Count=" + Integer.toString(mThumbIds.size()));
           // return 5;
            return mThumbIds.size();

        }

        public Object getItem(int position) {
            return null;
        }

        public long getItemId(int position) {
            return 0;
        }

        // create a new ImageView for each item referenced by the Adapter
        public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
            ImageView imageView;
            if (convertView == null) {
                // if it's not recycled, initialize some attributes
                imageView = new ImageView(mContext);
                imageView.setAdjustViewBounds(true);
                imageView.setScaleType(ImageView.ScaleType.FIT_XY);

            } else {
                imageView = (ImageView) convertView;
            }

            Picasso.with(getActivity()).load(mThumbIds.get(position)[0]).into(imageView);
            return imageView;
        }

    }


}
```

Comment: Do you have any data at the time of loading?

Comment: I am calling the updateMovieThumbs method to populate the listarray and then initiate the adapter.